# SQL, BETWEEN по дате без учета года

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно написать запрос для выборки интервала времени но с игнорированием года.
Те. например есть интервал '31.07 22:00:00' - '31.08 22:00:00' и нужно пробежатся по таблице игнорируя год и выбрать в таком промежутке все вхождения.
(вариант создания отдельного запроса для каждого года отдельно -  не комильфо)

для Between нужен год, подскажите пожалуйста как быть в таком случае?

Использую mysql 5.6

Comment: Самый простой способ поставить substr перед between, другой вариант - посмотреть ф-ции работы с датой для mysql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select * from table
  where DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m%d%h%i') between '07312200' and '08312200'
```

Обратите внимание, формат записи даты Месяц-День-Часы-Минуты, что бы сравнение на интервал правильно работало.

Comment: работает, спасибо !!!

Comment: А есть ли какое-либо решение, которое бы использовало индекс (если учесть, что поле `date` индексировано)?

Comment: @MaxU Это невозможно, по определению двоичного дерева поиска, используемого для индексации в базах данных. Дерево само строится по больше-меньше, причем всего значения в целом. Для использования индекса нам надо искать по неким интервалам (за каждый год отдельно). значит эти интервалы надо во первых сгенерить, во вторых, объяснить оптимизатору что индекс при этом надо использовать (он индекс обычно даже при обычном OR уже не использует). И если первое худо-бедно выполнимо, то второе маловероятно

Comment: @Mike, а как на счет использования [Generated (Virtual) columns](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/29/generated-virtual-columns-in-mysql-5-7-labs/)?

Comment: @MaxU Если у вас MySQL версии 5.7 то почему бы и нет. В других БД это называется функциональный индекс и работает автоматом. т.е. строим индекс прямо по выражению `date_format(...)`и оптимизатор для подобного запроса начинает использовать его. Ну тут немного кривой путь с виртуальными колонками придумали ... А ТС даже в вопросе указал что у него 5.6

Comment: @Mike, да в Oracle я бы сразу `function-based index` построил и забыл бы об этой задаче - поэтому и спрашивал по поводу MySQL...